# install cuda without prompt in docker

Tags: docker, ubuntu-16.04, nvidia, nvidia-docker

I am trying to build a docker container with cuda using the following piece in the docker build part

```
RUN wget -O $MRCNN_DIR/cuda-repo-ubuntu1604_9.0.176-1_amd64.deb http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu1604/x86_64/cuda-repo-ubuntu1604_9.1.85-1_amd64.deb && \
    dpkg -i $MRCNN_DIR/cuda-repo-ubuntu1604_9.0.176-1_amd64.deb && \
    apt-key adv --fetch-keys http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu1604/x86_64/7fa2af80.pub && \
    apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y cuda-9.0
```

This gives me a prompt for keyboard-config at build time. 
`debconf: unable to initialize frontend:`

How can I suppress this? Or am I doing the wrong thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have to set ENV in your dockerfile

```
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive
```